# How can I display a default value if the expected value is null?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Is there away to display a default value if the expected value is `null`?

Ex.

```html
<v-card-subtitle class="py-0 my-0">{{ user.name??'n/a' }}</v-card-subtitle>
```

Comment: In the `script` part, you could have `name: fetchedNameFromAPI || 'n/a'`.

Comment: Does it has to be in the script part ?  I am inside the view part.

Comment: As told in my previous comment: `In the script part etc...`, so yeah.

Comment: I mean, you could have the conditional in the `template` too, but I do not really recommend putting too much things there. Probably not a idea in general. Keep the template simple and make all of your logic in the script part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really** want it in the template, you could use

```html
<v-card-subtitle class="py-0 my-0">{{ user.name || 'n/a' }}</v-card-subtitle>
```

But I do heavily recommend using it in the `script` section, will give you more flexibility and keep the `template` simple and clean.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with computed property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return { text: null }
  },
  computed: {
    textVal() {
      return this.text || 'n/a'
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p> {{ textVal }} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have several items that might need `'n/a'`, you could try this

```html
<v-card-subtitle class="py-0 my-0">{{ user.name | handleEmptyValue }}</v-card-subtitle>

<script>
import _ from "lodash";

export default {
  filters: {
    handleEmptyValue(value) {
      return _.isEmpty(value) ? "N/A" : value;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please do not import the **whole** lodash library tho. Bur rather use some tree-shakable solution like `import { isEmpty } from 'lodash-es'`.

Comment: Good point. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: Also, filters are not available anymore in Vue3 (were already deprecated at some point in Vue2), so it's probably not a long-term sustainable solution.